# How to use for loop to run sql query in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have 100 records in table A， I only list 4 here but please use loop to solve this question

```
A = ['A001', 'B001','C001','Bdd','djd.djsx']
AB = pd.DataFrame(A, columns = ['app_name']) 
AB

app_name
0   A001
1   B001
2   C001
3   Bdd
4   djd.djsx
```

I have SQL query looks like this

```
select COUNT (DISTINCT [R_ID]) 
from database_view
where [app_name] in ('A001')
```

I want to **use loop to execute the query for 100 times** and append the final result to the AB

What I tried is:

```
For i in AB:
    sql = '''select COUNT (DISTINCT [R_ID]) 
from database_view
where  [app_name] in {i}'''

    a=pd.read_sql_query(sql,database)
    final = AB.append(a,ignore_index = True)
final
```

but it does not work, and also I find it will add one more column to the right of df"AB", but it will append the count number to a new row at last.

**Expected Result looks likes this,**
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV9sj.png)

it means for app A001, it has 6 different R_ID,
for app B001 it has 1 different R_ID

Any help is really appreicated!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just upload a pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a single aggregate query using `GROUP BY` without any for-loop and the need to append to data frame. Once SQL query runs, filter result with [**DataFrame.query**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to your list of 100 apps.

```py
sql = '''SELECT [app_name], COUNT(DISTINCT [R_ID]) AS r_id_count
         FROM database_view 
         GROUP BY [app_name]
      '''

apps = AB["app_name"].tolist()

app_counts_df = (
    pd.read_sql_query(sql, database)
      .query("app_name == @apps")
)
```

Comment: This works! but sorry cause the database has some issues, so when the app name equals to some specific one, e.g., when app_name = a.b.c, it can get the count number. But when app_name = t.b, it shows error "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint."

Is there some way, e.g, do a loop, if sql query fails, store that app_id to a failed_list, if sql query success, store the app_id to a success_list, and then when filter result, only enter the success_list

I know it's a little bit complicated, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hmmm... I cannot see how that error occurs with the SQL I posted. Are you running some other query?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put column name in for loop and f-string in SQL query. Try this code:

```
for i in AB['app_name']:
    sql = f'''select COUNT (DISTINCT [R_ID]) 
from database_view
where  [app_name] in {i}'''
```

Update-1: Edit SQL query:

```
# Create an empty dataframe:
df=pd.DataFrame()

for i in AB['app_name']:
    sql = f'''select app_name,COUNT (DISTINCT [R_ID]) 
from database_view
where  [app_name] in {i}
GROUP BY app_name'''
    a=pd.read_sql_query(sql,database)
    final = df.append(a,ignore_index = True)

print(final)
```

Comment: How I can append the count number to the AB table?